# What is the equivalent of the "President's Council on Sports, Fitness & Nutrition" in the People's Republic of China?

Tags: usa, china

> The President’s Council on Sports, Fitness & Nutrition (PCSFN) is a
> federal advisory committee that aims to promote healthy eating and
> physical activity for all Americans, regardless of background or
> ability.

https://health.gov/our-work/nutrition-physical-activity/presidents-council

Does such an analog exist in PR China?

Comment: How does this have anything to do with Expatriates or expatriation?

Comment: Does this fit better on [Politics.SE]?  Otherwise, could you please [edit] your question to explain the practical problem you are facing?